# File exists but mv errors out with: "mv: cannot stat ‘file.tar.gz’: No such file or directory"

Tags: shell, mv

I am creating a script in Centos 7 to move the latest file within a directory to another directory. The original directory that I'm copying from contains a valid file, however when I try to move or copy the file it errors out saying the file does not exist. I know the file does exist as I prove below. Why does it fail and what I can do to fix it?

If I run this line from my script in the shell the `$(` expands the output into the variable as expected:

```
NEW=$(ls -Art /home/user/directory/ | tail -1)
```

I can prove this to myself be echoing the value of the variable like so:
echo $NEW

```
file.tar.gz
```

Then I try to move the file to a different directory:

```
mv $NEW /usr/local/directory/
```

..and this is where I get the error. Note that the error message explicitly names the file it cannot find:

> mv: cannot stat ‘file.tar.gz’: No such file or directory

The shell appears to be telling me that it can't find the file and then naming the file it can't find.

I have tried replacing the backticks with parentheses but same result. I have tried changing the permissions of both the file and the directories above it to pretty much every permutation I can think of and also changed ownership to user.user

I have tried running the command as both root and user, same result each time. I will appreciate any attempt to help resolve this.

Comment: What are the back slashes, and use of back ticks is deprecated, you should do `NEW=$(ls -Art /home/user/directory/ | tail -1)`

Comment: I did not use back slashes originally, someone else kindly edited my question to include them. However I duly note your suggestion to use brackets

Comment: Back ticks are hard to do on stackoverflow as they are used to quote code. May be you question had a formatting error, that they tried to fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks that you are not in the directory where file is.

You use

```
 ls -Art /home/user/directory/
```

which return into NEW only the filename part, not the directory part.

Your move command should be

```
mv "/home/user/directory/$NEW"  /usr/local/directory/
```

Comment: Thank you Archemar, this has made me realize that I need to specify an exact location for the source file! It works!

Comment: Interestingly I have a similar problem with SCP giving me the same error, however I have three separate files to transfer and strangely enough two of them transfer fine using the original syntax. I'm wondering whether I should upload the script and error here or whether I should open a new question?

Comment: Post a new question if context is very different.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively ;

```
NEW="/home/user/directory/"`ls -Art /home/user/directory/ | tail -1`
```

Then your `mv` command as usual.

```
mv "$NEW" /usr/local/directory/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try `ls -Art /home/user/directory` by itself, you will notice that it outputs only filenames with no directory path component.  This means that your `NEW` variable lacks the `/home/user/directory` bit at the start of the pathname to the file.

Adding this to `NEW` would make your command work, assuming "nice" filenames (no newlines or other whitespace, nor any filename globbing characters), and assuming you're happy taking *whatever* filename that `tail` outputs, even if it's the name of a directory.

A better way to solve your issue of moving the most recently modified regular file from a directory to another is to use the `zsh` shell:

```bsh
mv /home/user/directory/*(.Dom[1]) /usr/local/directory
```

The `(.Dom[1])` is a globbing qualifier that makes the preceding pattern only match regular files (`.`), makes it possibly match hidden names (`D`, acts like the `dotglob` shell option in `bash`), orders the resulting list by modification timestamp (`om`), and picks out the first element from the sorted list (`[1]`).

From `bash` or any other shell:

```bsh
zsh -c 'mv /home/user/directory/*(.Dom[1]) /usr/local/directory'
```